# SSH Port Forwarding for dynamic IP

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

I want to create iptables rules to allow SSH port forwarding from a router with a public IP address (say 1.2.3.4) on port 2222 to a device with a local IP (192.168.x.x) on same port. One issue is I'm not sure what the rules actually look like, another is the person from outside trying to connect has a dynamic IP. How can I securely grant him access (ONLY him) without having to change the rules everytime the IP address changes? Can MASQUERADE be used? I've read documentation and other questions for hours, but am still not 100% confident of the solution.

LE: What I have so far is (beware that I didn't add them yet):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.x.x:2222 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 3.3.3.3 --dport 2222 -j MASQUERADE
```

I'm not sure if instead of having POSTROUTING, it should be FORWARD. Also, not sure if MASQUERADE should be used, I was thinking of ACCEPT?

Neither am I using the -i  parameter. Should this be used explicitly?

Comment: Could you add to your question what you've come up with so far?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Done. Please see my updated question.